# Threading, Tasks and variables correct approach

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a web api method that initiates work that could potentially take a long time so I would like to hand over this work to a new thread and return back to the caller.

In the code below I have defined an Action that will initiate n number of workflows. My question relates to variables defined outside of the Action method.

Is it safe to be utilizing memberManager and workflowDefinitionName inside of the Action?

As the InitiateBulkDischargeWorkflow method returns straight away, will the memberManager and workflowDefinitionName continue to be available within the Action block of code?

I have not done a lot of threading before so I am trying to improve my knowledge and am looking for feedback on the code so far.

Example code:

```
public class MemberController : ApiController {
    private readonly IMemberManager memberManager;
    public MemberContoller(IMemberManager memberManager) {
        this.memberManager = memberManager;
    }

    protected int CurrentUserId { 
        get {
            // removed
        }
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public void InitiateBulkDischargeWorkflow(string workflowDefinitionName, IDictionary<string, object> args)
    {
        args["argInitiatorId"] = CurrentUserId;

        // removed - ensure args are valid

        Action<object> action = (x) =>
        {
            var args2 = (IDictionary<string, object>) x;
            foreach (var memberId in (List<int>)args["argMemberIds"]) {
                try {
                    // create new dictionary
                    var memberArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    memberArgs["argMemberId"] = memberId;
                    memberArgs["argInitiatorId"] = args2["argInitiatorId"];
                    // further dictionary configuration here

                    // long running process
                    memberManager.InitiateWorkflow(initiatorId, memberId, workflowDefinitionName, memberArgs);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.ErrorFormat("Error initiating workflow '{0}' for memberid={1} by userid={2} in InitiateBulkDischargeWorkflow", e,
                        workflowDefinitionName, memberId, CurrentUserId);
                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(action, args);

        // return immediately, let thread handle creation of workflows
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Just a small hint - don't do `catch (Exception e)` ever. It's one of the best ways to introduce bugs and make your code undebuggable. You should only ever catch the specific exception that you are trying to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code compiles, then the variables are available for use. Whether it's *safe* or not is a different matter. In your question, the best anyone can say given the code shown so far is "it depends".

The `workflowDefinitionName` variable is fine for sure. The variable itself is a local variable, not modified by the named method or the anonymous method inside, and the object is a `string` which, being immutable, is inherently thread-safe.

The `memberManager` variable is different. The variable itself, presumably the one in the `MemberController` type, though your code example doesn't make this clear, is fine to use in the anonymous method as you do. However, note that if you have more than one thread access the *object* at a time, you may need to add synchronization to ensure that happens safely.

Without a better code example, I can't say what kind of synchronization would be needed. But it's likely you need something for that object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems overly complex. The more complex the more likely it'll have errors.

You're doing some weird indirection when you use the value `args2["argInitiatorId"]` to build the `memberArgs` dictionary. The value for `args2["argInitiatorId"]` is just `CurrentUserId` so why not just directly use that?

Also, don't do `catch (Exception e)` ever. It's one of the best ways to introduce bugs and make your code undebuggable. You should only ever catch the specific exception that you are trying to handle.

Here's my suggestion to make your code simpler:

```
public void InitiateBulkDischargeWorkflow(
    string workflowDefinitionName,
    IDictionary<string, object> args)
{
    var tasks =
        from memberId in args["argMemberIds"] as List<int>
        let memberArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "argMemberId", memberId },
            { "argInitiatorId", CurrentUserId },
        }
        select Task.Run(() =>
            memberManager.InitiateWorkflow(
                initiatorId,
                memberId,
                workflowDefinitionName,
                memberArgs));

    Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

I hope this helps.